# Combine two docker images into one

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, dockerfile

The title may be a bit weird and misleading, basically what I want to do is:

I need a node.js server that runs the following script from the dockerfile below. I don't want to run docker inside docker, so I need to combine the script and nodejs server, but don't know how, since I'm quite new to docker.

Should I add a configuration for the node js environment in the dockerfile below, or create a new dockerfile that depends on this one? And what should I do? Nevertheless, how do I do it?

```
FROM leon/usd:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/ufg

# Configuration
ARG UFG_RELEASE="3bf441e0eb5b6cfbe487bbf1e2b42b7447c43d02"
ARG UFG_SRC="/usr/src/ufg"
ARG UFG_INSTALL="/usr/local/ufg"
ENV USD_DIR="/usr/local/usd"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${USD_DIR}/lib:${UFG_SRC}/lib"
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${UFG_INSTALL}/bin"
ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${UFG_INSTALL}/python"

# Build + install usd_from_gltf
RUN git init && \
    git remote add origin https://github.com/google/usd_from_gltf.git && \
    git fetch --depth 1 origin "${UFG_RELEASE}" && \
    git checkout FETCH_HEAD && \
    python "${UFG_SRC}/tools/ufginstall/ufginstall.py" -v "${UFG_INSTALL}" "${USD_DIR}" && \
    cp -r "${UFG_SRC}/tools/ufgbatch" "${UFG_INSTALL}/python" && \
    rm -rf "${UFG_SRC}" "${UFG_INSTALL}/build" "${UFG_INSTALL}/src"

RUN mkdir /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app
# Start the service

ENTRYPOINT ["usd_from_gltf"]
CMD ["usd_from_gltf"]
```

Answer (score -1):

In Node's case, you can basically just splat in the instructions to download the Node.js tarball and unpack it in place. This is based on [the official Node dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3/13/stretch/Dockerfile) which does some more authenticity checking, etc.

```
RUN \
  cd /tmp \
  && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v13.12.0/node-v13.12.0-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
  && tar -xJf "node-v13.12.0-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner \
  && rm "node-v13.12.0-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
  && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs
```

If you also need the Yarn package manager, the instructions for adding it are in that same linked dockerfile.

Another option, [since it looks like `leon/usd` is using a Debian/Ubuntu base image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/leon/usd/latest/images/sha256-aeaacc84920686588ee30a7b2595872cfdd15be62a98ac4ec9e3d3ccf2a5904b?context=explore), is to just install Node.js using the image's Linux distribution's package manager, e.g. `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nodejs`.

Comment: The full node image comes with python 2.7 so it can build native npms... might be easier the other way around.